# How to deploy Django REST Framework and React app to AWS?

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services

I made an app using Django REST Framework as the backend and React as the frontend. It works on localhost.

Now I am trying to deploy the app to AWS.

When I follow the tutorial for deploying the Django app on AWS Beanstalk it worked for the API. I am able to use Postman and access the endpoints.

When I go to the URL, I get 404, debug is on:

```
Using the URLconf defined in dca.dca.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^api/dcasetting/$ [name='dcasetting-list']
    ^api/dcasetting\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='dcasetting-list']
    ^api/dcasetting/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='dcasetting-detail']
    ^api/dcasetting/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='dcasetting-detail']
    ^$ [name='api-root']
    ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
    api/auth
    api/auth/register
    api/auth/login
    api/auth/user
    api/auth/logout [name='knox_logout']

The current path, index.html, didn’t match any of these.
```

EDIT:

When I go to the base url:

It seems the `http://django-env.eba-3.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/` is trying to and succeding in loading the correct file: `http://django-env.eba-3.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/frontend/main.js`. I can see the template code on inspecting the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fort</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then it runs into a `404` when loading the main.js script. Would this be a path related error? Anyway to check this?

Then I tried one of the paths being tried above:

`api/auth/login`

This gives me error:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://django-env.eba-3.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/auth/login
Django Version:     4.0.6
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

rest_framework/api.html

Exception Location:     /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/python
Python Version:     3.8.5
Python Path:    

['/var/app/current',
 '/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin',
 '/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin',
 '/usr/lib64/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/var/app/current/dca']
```

The folder structure:

```
my_app
|-.ebextensions
|-.elasticbeanstalk
|-MyApp
   |-accounts
   |-MyApp
   |-MyAppsett
   |-frontend
   | manage.py
   | db.sqlite3
|-node_modules
| .babelrc
| package-lock.json
| package.json
| pipfile
| pipfile.lock
| requirements.txt
| webpack.config.js
```

I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: The error first error message is self-descriptive. It seems you don't have a path configuration matching with the first request you made in your Django app. 

In the output of the second request, it says that you are using GET method to login, which seems suspicious to me. Can you please try sending a POST request instead of GET?

Comment: @MertCanatan I am working on the first request. It seems the `http://django-env.eba-3.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/` is trying to and succeding in loading the correct file: `http://django-env.eba-3.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/frontend/main.js`. Then it runs into a `404` when loading the main.js script. Would this be a path related error? Anyway to check this?

Comment: `<script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>` error is coming from here. Should I move the static folder to top directory?

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge on Django but it definitely looks like static files are not served correctly, hence `main.js` is not loaded correctly.